# Pandas not storing changes for two functions unless these are separated by another operation on the DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, types

I was applying two methods to pandas.DataFrame (df) to change the data types of the columns:

```
df = df.applymap(function1)  # Removes symbols: "$"," ", ","
df = df.apply(function2)  # pd.to_numeric
```

However, it wasn't saving the changes unless I separated them by another operation on the df.

I'm trying to understand why is this happening. If you know, please let me know.

[image: capture: dataframe not saving changes]
———
I'm a using a self-hosted Google Colab notebook

- Python 3.6.12  build: h5500b2f_2
- Pandas 1.1.1   build: py36ha925a31_0

Comment: Have you try tro print the types just after the 2nd apply ? when they are next to each other

Comment: Yes. At some point, I did so, but it's wasn't saving the changes.